# How to start JBoss AS with external IP NAT

Tags: jboss, amazon-ec2, nat

I want to start JBoss AS with external IP NAT address. I have hosted JBoss AS in an Amazon EC2 Instance. Amazon EC2 manages two categories of addresses: public and private ip address (also public and private dns). I have started JBoss AS binded to public DNS using `run.sh -b public_dns` but in the console showed the the JBoss AS is starting with **private dns**.

Also when trying to connect to the server with an external client that don't exists in Amazon EC2 Network, an exception is thrown as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238567/cannt-connect-to-jboss-esb-hosted-in-amazon-ec2-machine and the server don't answer.

Comment: Please share configuration file and complete solution. It will help others like me.

Answer (score 0):

If your node only has a private IP address, then this would explain your issue. It is impossible to use a NAT translated IP address to connect to a node with only a private address, unless you start using NAT traversal and hole punching techniques.

This would be a complicated solution. The easy solution to make sure your node is assigned a public IP address. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for configuring JBoss behind a firewall (NAT)